# Is it possible to apply xml Templates in JAVA DSL Runner

Tags: citrus-framework

we have a lot of old citrus xml Testcases and templates in our Projects. After Upgrading to newer version I decided to make the switch to Java DSL. Is it possible to keep using the old templates? If i Try to do so, I get a "No bean named .. is defined" exception.

I tried the to import the template file via @ImportResource but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple custom test action that loads the template and executes it with current test context:

Given the following template in `templates/hello-template.xml`

```
<spring:beans xmlns="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                              http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase/citrus-testcase.xsd">
  <template name="helloTemplate">
    <echo>
      <message>Hello ${user}</message>
    </echo>
  </template>

</spring:beans>
```

You can write a custom test action for loading that template:

```
public class TemplateTest extends TestNGCitrusTestRunner {

    @Test
    @CitrusTest
    public void test() {
        run(new CallTemplateAction("templates/hello-template.xml", "helloTemplate"));
    }

    private class CallTemplateAction extends AbstractTestAction {
        private final String templateName;
        private final String templateLocation;

        public CallTemplateAction(String templateLocation, String templateName) {
            this.templateLocation = templateLocation;
            this.templateName = templateName;
        }

        @Override
        public void doExecute(TestContext testContext) {
            Template template = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { templateLocation }, 
                                         testContext.getApplicationContext())
                                        .getBean(templateName, Template.class);

            template.getParameter().put("user", "foo");
            template.execute(testContext);
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably cache the template instance and/or close the application context when done with the action.